# Overwrite content of messages_en.properties from an external messages_en.properties

Tags: spring-boot, external

I have a messages_en.properties inside the classpath (src/main/resources) and one outside the jar, in /config folder. But the messages_en.properties(content) in the /config folder doesn't overwrite the content which is inside the classpath, even after adding this tag:

spring.config.location=config/messages_en.properties

Am I going wrong or this is not possible at all in spring boot?

Do note, the application.properties is in the /config folder (externalized configuration).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're configuring `spring.config.location`,  which is used to provide the location of the external application configuration ([externalized configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)).

If you want to refer to an external location you should prefix your path with `file:`, for example:

```
spring.config.location=file:config/application.properties
```

---

However, when you use a file called **messages_en.properties** it's more likely that this is the properties file used by a [`MessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) (for internationalization/localization) rather than using it as a replacement for your application.properties file.

You can configure an external location for these messages as well, by configuring the `spring.messages.*` properties, for example:

```
spring.messages.basename=file:config/messages
```

You don't have to add the language code (`en`), because that's the convention used by Spring already for detecting the proper messages file.

Depending on the given language when calling the `MessageSource`, it will either open messages_en.properties or messages_fr.properties or ... and use messages.properties as a fallback if there is no property found for the provided language.

EDIT: It appears that the [`MessageSourceAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L179-L180) only kicks in for classpath resources **and** you need to have a default fallback **messages.properties**. If you don't have those, it will not work.

However, you can still use those properties and create a `MessageSource` manually using `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```java
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.messages")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    return new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
}
```

Comment: It worked a couple of times(two restarts of applications), but after that, it's now picking up the messages_en.properties which is defined inside the classpath and external(i.e config/messages_en.properties) is not overriding the one inside. Now, if I remove the one inside the classpath, it starts saying that the properties not found anymore. 

Can you let me know where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you try creating a `MessageSource` bean explicitly (`@Bean`) with the external configuration and make it primary (`@Primary`)? I guess that somehow Spring is creating another `MessageSource` bean that uses the classpath messages.

Comment: Created a bean. 

@Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        //messageSource.setBasenames("file:C:\\Users\\pavan.rao\\Documents\\mobiquity\\txn\\target\\config\\messages", "classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setBasenames("file:config/messages", "classpath:messages");
        return messageSource;
    }

Now, if I use the absolute path, it picks up, without the absolute path, it's not working. Any idea?

Comment: Ignore the above comment.. It was my issue.. But, essentially, I really wished it work through application.properties in external location(in debug mode, I see it getting picked, but doesn't work).

Comment: You're right, I took a dive into the Spring code and they explicitely look for classpath resources: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.java#L179-L180

Comment: @Pavanraotk I edited my answer with a solution, where you'll still be able to use the properties.

Comment: Works like a charm, and 2 lines fewer than my code and better maintainable too since now, the basenames are added in application.properties, not in the java class.

Thanks again. Is there a way I can give more votes?